# What does !$scope mean in angularJS/Ionic?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-scope

In terms of this line using Ionic:

```
if (!$scope.yelp.isLoading && $scope.yelp.hasMore) {
```

What does `!$scope` mean? How is that different than `$scope`? And why after the `&&` do you do `$scope` and not `!$scope`?

(Note: new to this so please explain in layman's terms)

Comment: Please read up on javascript operators . It is [Logical NOT Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT_%28!%29)

Comment: It isn't `!$scope` ... it is `!$scope.yelp.isLoading` ... big difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is quite simple and is the same as to any logic in any language where you used compare.
In your case, !$scope.yelp.isLoading will return true if $scope.yelp.isLoading is  false, and $scope.yelp.hasMore will return true or false associated with the value of $scope.yelp.hasMore i.e., true if true and false if false.

$scope is simply the object that is created by angularjs automatically which binds the elements of dom in scripting part.

About the question of using $scope and !$scope in the binding, is by far the simplest comparing logic. You are checking if yelp.isloading is false and yelp.hasmore is true you insert inside the if logic. (the logical and operator i.e. && suggests you to have both yelp.isloading=false and yelp.hasmore = true to go inside if statement).

You need to read the documentation of angularjs and also the basic programming operators.

Comment: Well explained Alex!!

Comment: Thank you, I have a services.js file with this code, and is that where I would find the value inside the scope object?: 
app.service("YelpService", function ($q, $http) {
 var self = {
  'page': 1,
  'isLoading': false,
  'hasMore': true,
So basically, like you said (but to be clear) is the line saying if the loading is true (because it is !$scope) and yelp has more data (has more is true) then ...? Is that right?

Comment: !true = false, !false=true, so if your isloading=false !isloading=true, and if your isloading=true !isloading=false, thats what the condition implies so !$scope.yelp.isloading will return true if $scope.yelp.isloading=false and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

**!** symbol means negation. e.g if **x** variable value is **true**, the negation **!** inverts the **x** value to **false** and vice versa.

```
 !$scope.yelp.isLoading
```

The sentence is not evaluating **$scope** per se, **$scope.yelp.isLoading** is the evaluated variable.

**$scope.yelp** is an object and the sentence is acceding to **isLoading** element.

e.g

```
$scope.yelp = {
   hasMore: false
   isLoading: true,
   ...
} //  $scope.yelp.isLoading === true , !$scope.yelp.isLoading === false
```

Answer (score 0):

*@Sah ( I can't comment )*.

> And why after the && do you do $scope and not !$scope?

It wouldn't be applied to the second condition because your code probably needs the first condition to be true and the second to be false at the same time . 
We need you to post more of the business code to understand what's meant to be done if both conditions are satisfied.